# Apache2 vs. PHP.ini compression

Tags: apache-2.2, compression

Are there any benefits to using Apache2s' mod_deflate compression over setting `zlib.output_compression = On` and `zlib.output_compression_level = 1` in php.ini?

I'm trying to come up with a good compression strategy which compresses all PHP output, plus.css and .js files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compression settings in your php.ini naturally only work with PHP scripts. If you want to compress your assets too, you need to use your Apache httpd's facilities.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I should have asked if there is any benefit to splitting up the compression duties between PHP and Apache2, or should I just use Apache2 to compress everything? The php.ini `zlib` seems to compress all PHP output perfectly with very minimal CPU overhead when set to `level 1`.

Comment: Followup... my research seems to show that using zlib in php.ini instead of Apache2s' mod_deflate speeds up output of PHP a little bit.